# How to load arrays to chart?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have seven userforms that follow the same logic. Each userform has an individual "controller" subroutine that guides the process to display charts in the userform.

I have a set of raw data on a sheet in Excel.

When the userform initialises it calls the required "controller" sub. The "controller" sub then calls another subroutine that accesses my raw data set, where a data range is determined.

Once the data range is determined I use this information in the next sub where I build my arrays. I build the arrays, upon returning to the controller sub.

Once the arrays have been built I call my sub to build my charts.

I am trying to pass these arrays to the required charts and then export them as needed to the userform to display them.

```vb
Sub mainUserForm(theVar As Integer)
    
    Dim myVar As Integer
    
    myVar = theVar
    
    'first get the date range
    Call getDataRange(False, 0, 0, myVar)
    
    'next the arrays
    If myVar = 1 Or myVar = 2 Then
        Call mainArrays(False)
        
    Else
        Call mainArrays(True)
    End If
    
    'next build required charts
    Call buildChartsMain(myVar)
    
End Sub
```

Now, for the problem. I use `Debug.Print Join(mainArray1)` the line before I add the array to the chart, however, the data displayed on the chart is incorrect. It is taking into account my whole data set and not a range.

When I print the values of the array they are correct, so the building process doesn't seem to be wrong.

I have declared all the required variables as `Public` for global use.

Blocks of my code below. Not sure what would be needed as everything seems to function until the charts part, which I think will take preference here.:

```vb
Sub buildChartsMain(myVar As Integer)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim mainChart1 As Shape, mainChart2 As Shape
    Dim myChartTitle As String
    Dim fileName1 As String, fileName2 As String
    
    myChartTitle = "My Chart Title"
    
    Set mainChart1 = wsRawData.Shapes.AddChart2(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=288, Height:=222)
    Set mainChart2 = wsRawData.Shapes.AddChart2(Left:=288, Top:=0, Width:=288, Height:=222)
    
    With mainChart1.Chart
        If myVar = 1 Or myVar = 2 Then
            Debug.Print Join(mainArray1)
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray1()
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = mainDateArray()
        Else
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray3()
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array("J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D")
        End If
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .ChartStyle = 209
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Text = myChartTitle
        .ChartArea.Font.Color = vbWhite
        .HasLegend = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Delete
    End With
    
    With mainChart2.Chart
        If myVar = 1 Or myVar = 2 Then
            Debug.Print Join(mainArray2)
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray2()
        Else
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray4()
        End If
        .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        .ChartStyle = 209
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Text = myChartTitle
        .ChartArea.Font.Color = vbWhite
        .HasLegend = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Delete
        .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
        .Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlHigh
    End With
    
    fileName1 = "G:\...\TempExcelCharts\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & "MGi.jpg"
    fileName2 = "G:\...\TempExcelCharts\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & "MTi.jpg"
    
    mainChart1.Chart.Export fileName:=fileName1, filterName:="JPG"
    mainChart2.Chart.Export fileName:=fileName2, filterName:="JPG"
    
    Call deleteAllCharts
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

The values from the array when printed are:

`-608.977899564394  -790.468111359605      261.83918034159      -2489.0105652811 1056.52810981723      -3180.41849515777  171.589419295134           -2137.41861594324        -3759.99257587681          5910.4390496604       2758.37807834967     -2597.07419574329`

But the chart ends up looking like this where clearly this is incorrect:

[image]

Comment: How many series are there on the chart at the end?

Comment: Supposed to be one collection per chart

Comment: Not "supposed to be" - how many are **actually** there?

Comment: Pretty sure you can remove the `()` from after the array variable names when using them like `mainArray1` instead of `mainArray1()`

Comment: One collection @Rory

Comment: Are you sure? It certainly looks like more than one in that picture. Off topic, IMO, that chart is hideous ;)

Comment: It's definitely one collection. The collection just spans my whole data range, thus, the hideousness. I promise when it works properly it doesn't look that bad! Back on topic, the collection is only supposed to contain 12 values, not a few hundred. When printing the values from the array they give the right values, but when loaded it doesnt load the array, but rather the whole range of data. Any ideas?

Comment: A chart has one _collection_, or rather one _SeriesCollection_. The SeriesCollection is a collection of all _Series_ in the chart. So say the chart has _one series_. The terminology is odd, I know.

Comment: @Rory Please see last comment by me on below answer and please see if you could assist with a solution for it please?

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the parentheses and turn this

```
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray1()
```

into this

```
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray1
```

Comment: Hi Jon. I have done this, this morning, and something has changed. Now the charts are being created with the first array, namely mainArray1. But both charts are showing the same data from mainArray1 instead of how it is supposed to be `mainChart1.Values = mainArray1` and `mainChart2.Values = mainArray2`. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem definitely seems to lie with how the data from the arrays is loaded to the chart. Do you know of any other logical ways to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: `mainChart1` and `mainChart2` are ChartObjects, right? So `mainChart1.Values` should give you a run time error 438, "Object doesn't support this property or method", the object being the ChartObject, the property or method being Values.

Comment: The `mainChart1.Values = mainArray1` was shorthand for `mainChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = mainArray1` See above in original post for code. At the moment the arrays don't contain more than 12-15 elements.

Comment: I have found the reason why this is occurring, but have no idea as to why this is the case. I have found that if the `ActiveCell` on my data sheet is within the range of the data set it then creates the chart using the range of the entire data set instead of the `mainArray1`. When I move the `ActiveCell` to outside of that range of the data it used the `mainArray1`. Any ideas how to prevent this, other than selecting a cell outside the range?

Comment: @Dean that was the point of my original question. Your code doesn't remove any existing series so I (still) suspect the code is creating the chart using all the values and then adding your smaller data set as a new series. You should loop to clear all existing series first.